# Invalid constraints in creo

Tags: computer-aided-design

I’m trying to assemble a pistol pin into a piston using creo parametric 5.

When I select the surface of the pin and the inside hole of the pistol this works fine and say that it is partially contrained.

However, when I select the planes front on the pin and the piston it says invalid constraint.

[image]

The first part of the image works fine but not the second part.

Any ideas why this may be ?

Comment: Try selecting origin point on the pin, rather than the plane. The concentric axis constraint already forces the planes to be parallel so mating plane to plane adds more constraints than is necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by origin point ?

Comment: And the origin point of the pin to the front plane  of the piston ?